# unknown number of children in ANTLR tree

Tags: java, regex, parsing, tree, antlr

I am working on a parser for a calculator, which also needs to build a tree.

For example:

```
exp returns[Tree tree]e1=exp e2=operator e3=exp{
    Tree tempTree = ($e2.tree);
    tempTree.insertChild ($e1.tree);
    tempTree.insertChild ($e3.tree);
    $tree = tempTree;
}
```

I would like to know how can I build a tree for a multiple arguments function without assuming number of children.
For example: `max(a,b,c,d,..)`

I thought of using something like `FUNCTION LEFTBRACKET exp (COMMA exp)* RIGHTBRACKET`

but I am not sure about building the tree for the * expression

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
FUNCTION: FUNCTION_NAME LEFTBRACKET PARAMETERS RIGHTBRACKET;
PARAMETERS: exp | exp COMMA PARAMEGERS;
```

may help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
I thought about it... but I thought it would create an unbalanced tree with many levels. How can I make all the children in the same depth?

Comment: @GalTannenbaum You could see this [link](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md#lexer-rule-elements), 5th line in the table. I think we can use * in the expression.

Answer (score 0):

What you did works fine, and the children will be put into a list that you can access via `expr()`.